# How do I check in Firefox and Chrome if a plugin is installed

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, google-chrome

I'm using an embedded plugin in my web app to enable scanning (Dynamsoft's webscanning plugin). I'm serving an xpi to firefox users and a crx to chrome users. When viewing the page without the plugin installed, Firefox will try to download the plugin and the user will need to click "manual install" to install it. Chrome will make no attempt to donwload the plugin (this is by design, according to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=15745)

I would like to use javascript to detect wether the plugin is installed or not (preferrably before trying to load it through the embed tag). If no plugin is installed, I want to provide an explanation and a link to the correct plugin to the user. Both browsers install their respective plugins without any problem if the user clicks at a download link instead of just trying to load through the embed tag.

So, does anybody know a way detect wether a plugin is installed using javascript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you had a look at [window.navigator.plugins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.plugins)?

<strike>..and the equivalent reference for webkit [plugins](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/WebKitDOMRef/Navigator_idl/Classes/Navigator/index.html#//apple_ref/js/data/Navigator/plugins)-</strike>

The Apple reference for the WebKit DOM appears to have disappeared.  `navigator.plugins` does work for me in Safari & Chrome.  See a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2EaKD/

Comment: Brilliant! I'll play with that a bit, but it definitely seems to be what I was looking for. Thankyou!!!

Comment: And we have a winner. Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Jens, did this work for you in webkit?, russau's link to webkit plugins is kind of broken (redirects to a new page) or not very clear

Comment: @knocte yes, the apple links has disappeared.  updated the answer with a link to a jsfiddle that works in Chrome/Safari

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me like a potential security hole, if a website (something remotely) could access your plug-ins (something locally). So I guess this is not possible.

Comment: It could be, but I wouldn't actually need to access the plugin, only know if it exists.

Comment: is it a bit of a 'privacy hole', as it can be used to fingerprint your browser.  see a demo here: https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Answer (score -1):

Your addon can monitor which pages are opened by the user. If it is your page, you can make your addon set a global variable in that page and your page's JavaScript should be able to detect this.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my plugin, though I could check with the maker of the plugin if they set som variable I could check. Preferrably I would like to check for the plugin before I try to embed it, to avoid prompts for installation without warning the user.

Comment: @Jens Alm: I see. Depending on the type of "plugin", @russau's answer might help.