# Test if User has Spotify Installed?

Tags: javascript, api, plugins, spotify

Is there a way via JavaScript to see if a person has Spotify installed on their machine.  Reason being, if they do, I will share some Spotify URI's on my page (example...  spotify:user:124792730:playlist:0Y2wUYw5wxMdZGCqJyqbaA).  If they don't, I would prompt them to install Spotify so they can listen to the Spotify URI's instead of serving them broken links.

There is a way to do this for Spotify APPS.  But What if I'm not making an app, I just want to serve Spotify URI links from web page only if they have Spotify already.

Update:  The following seems to only work on Firefox.  I think I'm close, though.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {
            location.replace("spotify:user:124792730:playlist:0Y2wUYw5wxMdZGCqJyqbaA");
        } catch (e) {
            alert("You don't have spotify Installed.");
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check in Firefox and Chrome if a plugin is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636407/how-do-i-check-in-firefox-and-chrome-if-a-plugin-is-installed)

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  There is no Spotify plugin or add-on listed in my browser's Add-ons manager.  I do have Spotify installed on this machine.

Comment: If it's not a plug-in, the browser cannot tell when you have installed on your machine.

Comment: I can test for it in Firefox.  Just need to find an equivalent for IE, Chrome, etc.

Comment: Possibly a more obscure duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872090/how-to-check-if-a-custom-protocol-supported

Comment: Kekoa, I think you're on the right track.

Comment: Unfortunately, protocol detection seems like a huge black hole.  Opera and Chrome (believe it or not) suck especially hard at detecting protocols.  I think James has the best answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

You could link to the HTTP version instead:

```
http://open.spotify.com/user/124792730/playlist/0Y2wUYw5wxMdZGCqJyqbaA
```

This presents a link to open the playlist in Spotify along with the option to install it.

Comment: The benefit of a Spotify URI over a Spotify HTTP link is that the URI opens the target playlist or song directly in Spotify.  The HTTP method is a two step process that first takes people to a web page where they can then click on a link.  I'm trying to avoid two steps for folks who already have Spotify.

Comment: You know, this option is looking better all the time.  If the user says "Yes I Have Spotify" once, they don't have to do it ever again unless they delete the cookies for ".spotify.com"  Unfortunately, they still have to have two windows open.  I wish I could detect if that cookie is set already from my domain.

Comment: Check the source of this page to see how we automatically launch the client once the user has clicked "I Have Spotify" once:

view-source:http://open.spotify.com/album/2PpT0B9E0IglzKhOZfMbQC