# Distinguish between chrome and chromium using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chromium

Is it possible to distinguish Google Chrome from the open source Chromium browser using Javascript? The `navigator.userAgent` property seems to be identical in both browsers.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you need this. Google Chrome is a Chromium build, so what difference are you looking for?

Comment: True, but Chromium does have some differences. In my case, I need to load a PDF preview into the browser window for printing. If the user is running chromium, it will download the PDF, since there is no PDF plugin for Chromium. With this in mind, I'd like to alter the chain of events slightly for users running Chromium only.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636407/how-do-i-check-in-firefox-and-chrome-if-a-plugin-is-installed

Comment: Interesting - I've never seen the `navigator.plugins` property before. It does seem like it might work well for my particular case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not want to just check for Chromium because Google Chrome's PDF plugin can also be used in Chromium (by simply copying the `.dll` file). In fact, I'm using it right now.

The best way is to check for the Chrome PDF plugin, using `window.navigator.plugins`:

```
var pdf = false;
for (i in window.navigator.plugins) {
    if (window.navigator.plugins[i].name === "Chrome PDF Viewer") {
        pdf = true;
    }
}
```

If you want to use the `filename` instead of the `name`, it's `"pdf.dll"` (on Windows machines).

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I am reluctant to use the chrome plugin because it is not open source and we are redistributing chromium so we might run into legal issues. This works well tho, thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I edited my answer a bit; you'll have to define `pdf` first before you use it.