# Recognize whether browser has plugin X installed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if this was possible!

I have a plugin, like this:

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/xxxxx-plugin"
        SOMECODE HERE/>
```

And if I don't have the plugin installed, in chrome I only get a page with a grey box telling me "plugin not installed" and in IE I don't even get a hint that there is a plugin (background instead of what should be the plugin), I wanted to know if there was any way to warn a user (perhaps with a javascript box?) that he doesn't have the plugin needed installed and where he could get it.

TL;DR:

1. I have a plugin
2. If visitor doesn't have plugin
3. How to warn him he doesn't have the plugin (eg javascript box?)

Thanks.

Comment: try this.:
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636407/how-do-i-check-in-firefox-and-chrome-if-a-plugin-is-installed