# Firefox addon inline installation from website

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, xpi

I am trying to work out how to best implement direct [firefox-addon](/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) installation from my website. Besides simply prompting the user to install the addon, I would also want to get the result of the user action (accepts installation or cancels it).

Research on google generally points to the use of `InstallTrigger.install()`, which works fine except that there is no functional callback that I can use to know the result of the user's action.

Though `InstallTrigger.install()` does accept a callback, the callback is not fired unless the current viewing page is a whitelisted domain (e.g. AMO):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XPInstall/Reference/InstallTrigger_Object/Methods/install

So I am wondering:

1. Is there any alternative way to get the result of the addon installation, and
2. Does [mozilla](/questions/tagged/mozilla) have anyway to accept a domain into their default addon installation whitelist.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: There is no solution. Only AMO is whitelisted.

Comment: A possible solution would be to make your addon send a ping to your server when it is installed. This way you indirectly know when a user accepts to install it.

Comment: @Marco, someone what half acceptable answer, you would know if they installed it but not rejected... Anyway another approach could be to send a postMessage to all/some window/tabs so you wouldn't need a server

Comment: sorry i cant comment yet so does this answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636407/how-do-i-check-in-firefox-and-chrome-if-a-plugin-is-installed

Answer (score 1):

Just to get this question off the Unanswered list.

The XPInstall whitelist [only contains Mozilla's sites](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/d96317a351af8aa78ab9847e7feed964bbaac7d7/browser/app/permissions#17-19), so Mozilla doesn't seem to have a way to accept a domain into their default addon installation whitelist.

The browser itself will not notify the untrusted web page about the results of the add-on installation. If your extension is restartless, it can notify the page it has been installed via `postMessage`.